# How can I decide which algorithm is more efficent for reverse an array

Tags: java, algorithm, reverse

I was trying to improve my self about algorithms.

So I've tried to reverse an array of integer values.

Here is my solution.

```
     static  int[] reverseArray(int[] arr){

    int[] newArr =new int[arr.length];

    for (int i = arr.length-1, j = 0; i>=0; i-- , j++){

        newArr[j] = arr[i];

    }

    return newArr;

}
```

And this is the solution  what i see as the answer on the site. So my mind is little confused. In my opion my solution is easier and better. I don't understand why we have to divide it in two for example I think  it's not necessary. So can anyone help me what's wrong with my solution?

```
 for(int i = 0; i < my_array1.length / 2; i++)

{

int temp = my_array1[i];
my_array1[i] = my_array1[my_array1.length - i - 1];
my_array1[my_array1.length - i - 1] = temp;

}
```

Comment: You solution creates a new array, which is a relatively expensive operation. The second solution reverse the array in-place, without the need for allocating a new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand, your algorithm needs twice as much memory as the other. Since you are creating a copy of the array, if the length of the array is 50, you need to reserve 50 more memory addresses. However, the other solution just will need to reserve 1 memory address (for 1 auxiliar `int`) regardless of the length of the original array.

On the other hand, your algorithm iterates all elements of the array while the other just needs to iterate to the midpoint.
Theoretically, both solutions have the same order of efficiency: `O(n)` but in reality the other solution does fewer iterations.

Comment: Number of iterations by themselves don't mean anything. The second solution does half the iterations, but twice as much work in a single iteration. That's why any constant factor is removed in the big-O notation. The only thing that matters is how the number of operations changes as the number of inputs change.